# RDP ceases due to encryption error, but only over wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, remote-desktop, encryption, wifi-configuration, throughput

So I'm trying to figure out some problems I'm having with RDP. It fails repeatedly over wifi due with the message

```
 "Because of an error in data encryption, this session will end"
```

It does not do this on a wired connection. The confusing part is, I know wifi throughput is not the bottleneck in most internet connections (that being the internet), and since wired rdp works over the internet, I can't really explain it away with just "Wifi isn't fast enough to handle RDP". Are there any settings in the adapter properties I could change to fix this?

Thank you,
Sidney

Answer (score 0):

Well, it appeared that the problem was with the sonic wall vpn client. Uninstall that (not just disable the adaptor, but uninstall it) and bam, it works.